# Dropdown with multiple select and can select same value multiple times

Tags: html, html-select, dropdown

I have a drop down like

```
<select multiple>
    <option>page1</option>
    <option>page2</option>
    <option>page3</option>
</select>
```

Please suggest me a frame work where we can select same value more than one time.

Comment: No framework will satisfy that condition. The options are supposed to be unique and that's the point of a select dropdown. Why would you need someone to select same option multiple times?

Comment: If this is not possible with select tag, please tell me how can I do that.